# Win 7 Create Folder Junction from Desktop to inside Dropbox Folder

Tags: windows-7, desktop, dropbox, junction

I'm not asking how it can be done, I already know how to;

```
MKLNK /j C:\Users\<username>\Desktop C:\Users\<username>\Dropbox\Desk
```

What I want to know is whether or not I should. I know that there must be drastic consequences and unforseen complications with doing this, so please convince me that I shouldn't before I destroy my computer's filesystem.

Comment: Why would there be issues? I have my github folder as a junction in dropbox, same for my documents.. why would desktop be different?

Comment: Yes;  I can think of one major reason this isn't a good idea.  The worst that will happen is your profile will become corrupt.

Comment: Why would your profile become corrupt? You can make a junction, but Dropbox will only follow junctions once per start of Dropbox. This is to prevent infinite crawling of cyclical junctions. This means, Dropbox will backup your Desktop once a day if you restart your computer once a day. It's better to use a free backup software like Bvckup (last beta is free) to perform backups to Dropbox when it detects change.